# What happens when I add character array with unsigned long in c?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void  double_string(char ary[])
{
  char *start = ary;
 // dont exactly know what is happening here nothing is getting printed when consoled
  char *end = ary + strlen(ary);
  char *org = end;

  while(start<org)
  {
     *end = *start;
     start++;
     end++;
  }
  *end = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
   char word[255] = {"TACsasasa"};
   double_string(word);
   printf("%s",word);
  return 0;
}
```

I am unable to understand what is getting stored in character array "*end", I tried printing it but I am not getting any output printed..

Comment: What are you expecting to happen

Comment: I am trying to understand the actual snippet of how the code works internally. why "*end" is not getting printed.. it's not about the result every time!! I am trying to figure out the concept behind... How actually start<org behaving?

Comment: When the line after your comment executes, `end` will point at the terminating null character of the original string. If you print `*end`, you shouldn't expect to get anything. The rest of the function will copy the original string starting at that point, so you get the original string doubled. So the function name `double_string` seems to agree with its effect. Does the behavior of the program differ from your expectations?

Comment: @FredLarson As the end pointer is pointing to the null and *org is pointing to the end pointer address as well..... How actually the comparision is happening  between start and org which is pointing to null..Please let me know

Comment: Be careful not confuse a pointer to a null character with a null pointer. `end` and `org` both point at the null terminator to begin with. But `end` gets incremented as the characters are copied to the end of the original string. `org` remains pointing to where the original string ended, so the `start<org` comparison tells when to stop copying.

Comment: @FredLarson Thank you very very much ..
*org = end // here org points to null pointer, where end pointer is shifted from addind strlen(ary)    `` ``
so org should also be null `` ``
But Start is pointing to the first element in the ary.... ```
How can first element in the ary less then null value which is pointed by null pointer org

Comment: The comparison is on the *pointers*, not the characters the pointers point to.

Answer (score 1):

`char *end = ary + strlen(ary);`

This line of code is taking the starting address of the char array in memory, adding the number of bytes inside the array, returned by strlen(), and essentially moving the pointer to the end. The end of the array is the null terminator. Printing that will show nothing as it takes it as an empty string.

Comment: My confusion is why  is it not returning type error when we are adding two different typed things...ary which is "character array" and strlen(ary) which is "unsigned long".. Please let me know

Comment: @satwik They are implicitly cast to types the compiler knows how to handle. + operator isn't always "adding", in this case it is moving a pointer a number of bytes. But it is almost like adding a number of bytes to a position in memory, to get a new position

Comment: Thank you.. but when I tried to check the sizeof the " *end " with different word lengths...I am always getting same size as 8..but infact if bytes increases size should increase isn't it ? or am  I thinking the wrong way?

Comment: @satwik You are probably thinking the wrong way. sizeof(end) is always 8 because end is a pointer and pointers take up 8 bytes on your computer. sizeof(*end) would always be 1 because *end is a char and chars are always 1 byte.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you very much I got it now but the only confusion is ..How actually the comparision is happening between start and org which is pointing to null..Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `unsigned int` (or even a signed `int`!) is known as *pointer arithmetic*. It's legal and quite common in C code.  You do have to be very careful about going out of the bounds of your memory buffer, though, or you will experience *undefined behavior*. This is bad. Fortunately, this code appears to be quite well behaved as long as the original string is less than half the length of its memory buffer.

Allow me to try some ASCII art to see if I can make clear what's going on in the `double_string` function. It starts with this:

```
   char *start = ary;
   char *end = ary + strlen(ary);
   char *org = end;
```

At this point, your pointers look like this:

```
    start                                end
      |                                   |
      |                                  org
      |                                   |
      v                                   V
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ary | T | A | C | s | a | s | a | s | a |\0 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | ...
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then we have the loop.

```
  while(start<org)
  {
     *end = *start;
     start++;
     end++;
  }
```

After the first loop iteration, it looks like this:

```
        start                                end
          |                                   |
          |                              org  |
          |                               |   |
          v                               V   V
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ary | T | A | C | s | a | s | a | s | a | T |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | ...
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Second iteration:

```
            start                                end
              |                                   |
              |                          org      |
              |                           |       |
              v                           V       V
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ary | T | A | C | s | a | s | a | s | a | T | A |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | ...
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And so on. The loop continues as long as `start` is less than (to the left of, in my illustration) `org`:

```
                                        start                                end
                                          |                                   |
                                         org                                  |
                                          |                                   |
                                          V                                   V
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ary | T | A | C | s | a | s | a | s | a | T | A | C | s | a | s | a | s | a |   |   | ...
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now `start<org` is no longer true, because they're equal. They point to the same location. The loop terminates. All that's left to do is terminate the string with `*end = '\0';`:

```
                                        start                                end
                                          |                                   |
                                         org                                  |
                                          |                                   |
                                          V                                   V
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ary | T | A | C | s | a | s | a | s | a | T | A | C | s | a | s | a | s | a |\0 |   | ...
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Best explanation I have ever got.... Thank you very much for sharing so many internal things which made concepts very clearer to me... Thank you again

Comment: Glad to be of service! Drawing things like this on paper can often help understand pointer issues.